# echo function is not showing any output

Tags: php, echo

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST["user_name"]) && isset($_POST["user_pwd"])) {
    include"php/connect_to_mysql.php";
    $user_name = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["user_name"]);
    $user_pwd = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["user_pwd"]);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_ac WHERE user='$user_name' OR email='$user_name' AND pwd='$user_pwd' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        echo "Successfully Logged In";
        header("location: login.html?abc=234");
    } else {

    }
} else {

}
```

In this code, inside the second `if` statement, `echo` is not displaying anything, but the `header` function executes correctly.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot see the echo because you are going to another page.

As test, remove the `header("location: login.html?abc=234");` and you will see the `echo`.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I also tried redirecting to same page but no successs

Comment: If you redirect to any page you won't see the echo

Comment: After removing the redirection line it worked. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

header function redirect you to new page, so your echo will appear in your current page but your code by this line:

```
header("location: login.html?abc=234");
```

will redirect you to new page.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I also tried redirecting to same page but no successs

Comment: After removing the redirection line it worked.
Thanks again